# Traumatic mydriasis (dilated pupil) information

Tags: statistics, lasting-effects-duration, trauma, pupil

How and when (if its possible) to say that traumatic mydriasis is going to be healed or stay forever?

Is there some specific signs or nobody can say that?

Is there any statistic data about it (succesfully recovered patients etc)?

**UPD (30.01.2017)**

As for me, for today  I still got mydriasis.

Was trying treatment with pylocarpine eye drops, seems like it's not effective

**UPD (07.02.2017)**

Used more than a week *pilocarpine 1%*.

No effect

**UPD (16.02.2017)**

Noticed that appeared weak pupil reaction on light (used my phone flashlight to checking it).

In the dark pupil approximately `6 mm` in diameter, when I turn light and set it close to eye - It shrinks to like `4 - 4.5 mm`

**UPD (10.03.2017)**

No futher improvement. As I assume it won't get better for now, so.
Take care of your eyes, guys, wear protection and be aware of the fireworks/party-poppers etc